# Wordpress/WooCommerce Internal Duplicate Content

Tags: wordpress, duplicates

My website is based on wordpress and woocommerce. There are too many pages which have duplicate content. Such as product pages with a little different description/price/model, but most of the content are the same. I am thinking about canonical tag, but there is not one for my situation. They are only added the canonical tag on any page with its own url. So is there any one who have better solution? I tried merge pages, but there are still so many duplicate-content pages left.